# Show that $B={\{x \in [0,1] : λ(E \cap (x−ε,x+ε)) > 0 \ \text{for all} \ ε>0 }\}$ is perfect.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0, 1]$, and define
> $B={\{x \in [0,1] : λ(E \cap (x−ε,x+ε)) > 0 \ \text{for all} \ ε>0 }\}$. Show that $B$ is perfect.

I have no idea how to approach the problem at all especially there are lots of confusions first to handle if I want to approach based on the definition of a perfect set : a nonempty, closed set which all its elements are limit points.

1- $B$ must be nonempty: how is it possible for some $x \in B$, for all $ε>0$, $λ>0$ when we can approach $ε$ to zero?

2- I can't see a way to show that any open neighborhood of any point in $B$ must intersect some different point $B$?

3- Why $B$ must be closed?

4- Are there any assumptions needed to be imposed on $E$ so that $B$ be a perfect, in the first place?

Comment: For $B$ to be non empty, I think some condition on $E$ is needed.  As the question is currently written, $B$ can be empty.  Take $E={0} $. $E$ is measurable, $E \subset [0,1]$ and $B=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Ramiro, I think for other parts of the definition of a perfect set also some conditions may be needed to impose on $E$ (?)

Comment: *based on the definition of a perfect set : a nonempty, closed set* $\cdots$ --- The usual definition of a perfect set does NOT require the set to be nonempty, but if this requirement is in Bruckner's book, then it's an editing oversight in the statement of the problem.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, No actually I used the definition from Rudin's 
Principles of Mathematical Analysis. If still I can get "all its elements are limit point" part, that's a huge step!

Comment: The result is an example of what I often call a "Cantor-Bendixson analogue". See the first part of [bof's answer to *A perfect nowhere dense set which intersects every open set with positive measure?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2993771/13130) and my comment there. One easily proved general version of the C-B theorem (goes back at least to Eugene Harold Hanson (1903-1990)'s 1934 Ph.D. dissertation) is: Let $\mathcal I$ be a $\sigma$-ideal in ${\mathbb R}^n$ and $E \subseteq {\mathbb R}^n.$ **(continued)**

Comment: Then $E = P \cup Z$ where $Z \in {\mathcal I})$ (i.e. $Z$ is "$mathcal I$-small") and $P$ is $\mathcal I$-dense at each point of $P$ (i.e. for each point $x \in P$ and each nonempty open set $U_x$ containing $x,$ the intersection $P \cap U_x$ does not belong to $\mathcal I).$ Moreover, if $\mathcal I$ contains all singleton sets, then $P$ is closed (and in this case, $P$ is sometimes called $\mathcal I$-perfect, since every point of $P$ is a limit point in a "strong way involving $\mathcal I$" of other points in $P).$ Bruckner's problem is when $\mathcal I$ is the set of Leb. measure $0$ sets.

Comment: The reason Bruckner requires the set $E$ to be measurable is to avoid the reader worrying about non-measurable sets. Thus in the Bruckner problem, when one is considering the situation where a set "does not belong to $\mathcal I$" (i.e. the sets involved do not have measure zero), then we know that the sets have positive measure (rather than we only know that the sets have positive outer measure, which allows for non-measurable sets).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I could understand the answer and all your comments partially and I don't think I can solve my problem unfortunately. Bruckner's book is much more elementary (so is my knowledge), and I think either there is an easy answer to the exercise or Bruckner has put it out there for a challenge?

Comment: @L.G. We can prove that B is closed and has no isolated points. This proof can be done using standard (basic) facts of Lebesgue measure  and Topology. Take a look in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $[0, 1]$, and define
> $B={\{x \in [0,1] : \lambda(E \cap (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)) > 0 \ \text{for all} \ \varepsilon>0 }\}$. Show that $B$ is perfect.

A perfect set is a closed set with no isolate points (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set)).
According to this definition, the empty set is a perfect set.

Let us prove the result.

**Proof**:

1. $B$ is closed: Let $a \in [0,1]$ and let $\{x_n\}_n$ be a sequence of points in $B$ converging to $a$.  So, given $delta > 0$ , there is $k$ such that $x_k \in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$. So, there is $\varepsilon >0$  such that $(x_k- \varepsilon, x_k + \varepsilon) \subseteq (a-\delta, a+\delta)$. Since $x_k \in B$, we have
   $$\lambda(E \cap (a- \delta, a + \delta)) >\lambda(E \cap (x_k- \varepsilon, x_k + \varepsilon)) > 0$$
   So $a \in B$. So, $B$ is closed.
2. $B$ has no isolate points: Let $x\in B$. Suppose $x$ is an isolated point. Then, there is  $\delta>0$, such that $(x- \delta, x+ \delta) \cap B=\{x\}$.
   Note that, by the definition of $B$,  $\lambda(E \cap (x- \delta, x+ \delta))>0$

So, for all $y \in (x- \delta, x+ \delta)$, such that $y \ne x$, we have that $y \notin B$. So, there is $\varepsilon >0$, such that
$$\lambda(E \cap (y- \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon)) =0$$
Let $r_y >0$ such that $r_y< \varepsilon$ and $(y-r_y, y+r_y) \subseteq (x- \delta, x+ \delta)$. Clearly, we have
$$0 \leq \lambda(E \cap (y- r_y, y + r_y))  \leq \lambda(E \cap (y- \varepsilon, y + \varepsilon)) =0$$
So, for all $y \in (x- \delta, x) \cup (x, x+ \delta)$, we have $\lambda(E \cap (y- r_y, y + r_y)) =0$.

Let $K$ be any compact set such that $K \subset (x- \delta, x) \cup (x, x+ \delta)$. It is easy to see that there is $n$ and $y_0, y_1, \cdots y_n$ such that $K \subset \bigcup_{i=0}^n(y_i-r_{y_i}, y_i+r_{y_i})$. So $\lambda(E \cap K)=0$.

So, for all  $K$ compact set such that $K \subset (x- \delta, x) \cup (x, x+ \delta)$, we have $\lambda(E \cap K)=0$. So
$$\lambda(E \cap ((x- \delta, x) \cup (x, x+ \delta)))=0$$
Since $\lambda(E \cap \{x\})=0$, we have
$$ 0 = \lambda(E \cap \{x\}) + \lambda(E \cap ((x- \delta, x) \cup (x, x+ \delta))) = \lambda(E \cap (x- \delta, x+ \delta))>0$$
Contradiction.
So $B$ has no isolated points.

Comment: You are amazing! Every time with a simple clear best answer ever! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Lebesgue measure analogue of the Cantor-Bendixson theorem I mentioned in the comments. Various parts of this proof can be used to prove what you want. Incidentally, while the analogous $\sigma$-ideal version was probably first proved in Eugene Harold Hanson (1903-1990)'s [1936 Ph.D. dissertation](https://www.mathgenealogy.org/id.php?id=10207), the first published proof was probably: Géza Freud (1922−1979), [*Ein beitrag zu dem satze von Cantor und Bendixson*](https://akjournals.com/view/journals/10473/9/3-4/article-p333.xml) [A contribution to the theorem of Cantor and Bendixson], **Acta Mathematica Academiae Scientiarum Hungaricae** [*later title*: **Acta Mathematica Hungarica**] 9 (1958), pp. 333−336.

**Definition:** Let $E \subseteq \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable and $x \in E.$ We say that $E$ is *metrically dense at* $x$ if the intersection of $E$ with each neighborhood of $x$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

**Theorem:** Let $E \subseteq \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable. Then $E = P \cup Z$ where $Z$ has Lebesgue measure zero and $P$ is a relatively closed subset of $E$ that is metrically dense at each point of $P.$

**Proof:** $[P$ is closed] Let $P$ be the set of points belonging to $E$ at which $E$ is metrically dense and let $Z = E - P.$ To see that the set $P$ is closed relative to $E,$ it suffices to show that $Z$ is open relative to $E,$ which is easy to see since each point of $Z$ has a neighborhood whose intersection with $E$ has zero Lebesgue measure, and each of the points in this neighborhood also have this property. This also follows from an equation at the end of this proof in which $Z$ is expressed as a union of $Z$-open sets.

$[P$ is dense-in-itself] $P$ is dense-in-itself (in a strong way) because if $P$ is not empty and $x \in P$, then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a positive measure subset of $E,$ and hence every neighborhood of $x$ contains a positive measure subset of $P$ (removing from $E$ the points in $Z$ will not affect Lebesgue measure; see also the "$E \, \Delta \, F$" observation below). Therefore, every neighborhood of $x$ contains points of $P$ other than $x.$

$[Z$ has Lebesgue measure zero] If we can show that $Z$ has Lebesgue measure zero, then it follows easily that $P$ is metrically dense at each point of $P.$ **[1]** This is because if $E$ and $F$ are such that $E \, \Delta \, F$ has Lebesgue measure zero, then $E$ is metrically dense at $x$ iff $F$ is metrically dense at $x.$ Thus, to complete the proof, we show that $Z$ has Lebesgue measure zero. To this end, note that each $x \in Z$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ such that $Z \cap U_x$ has Lebesgue measure zero. The collection of these neighborhoods is an open covering of $Z.$ By taking a countable subcover $\{U_{x_k}: \; x_k \in Z \; \text{where} \; k = 1,2,3, \ldots \}$ (use the Lindelöf property of the reals), and using the fact that a countable union of Lebesgue measure zero sets has Lebesgue measure zero, it follows that $Z = \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}(Z \cap U_{x_k})$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

**[1]** Note that "$E$ is metrically dense at $x$" is a weaker condition than "$P$ is metrically dense at $x$", since intersections with $E$ will be at least as large as (and often strictly larger than) intersections with $P,$ and thus the requirement that intersections with $P$ have positive measure is at least as strong as (and often strictly stronger than) the requirement that intersections with $E$ have positive measure.

Comment: +1 thanks a lot :)