# Set Of Density Points

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm curious about the following operator:  Take some set $A\subseteq\mathbf{R}^n$, return the set $D(A)$ of all points $x\in \mathbf{R}^n$ such that there is no neighbourhood $U\in\mathcal{N}(x)$ with $A\cap U$ being a (Lebesgue) null set.

- Is $D(A)$ always measurable (Borel or Lebesgue)?
- Is $D$ idempotent, i.e. $D(D(A))=D(A)$?
- What can be said about $D(A)\setminus A$, is it a null set?

If the first two questions don't return both true, is there some other way to obtain a measurable set $A'$ from $A$ with $D(A)=D(A')$?

#### EDIT

- I think $D(A)$ is always a Borel set.  Assume $n=1$, for $i\in\mathbf{N}$, let $A_i$ be the union of all intervals $I_{i,k}:=[k2^{-i},(k+1)2^{-i}]$ such that $A\cap I_{i,k}$ is not a null set.  Then $D(A)$ should be equal to $\cap_i A_i$ if I'm not mistaken.
- In $D(A)$ it seems like every point is also an accumulation point of the set, is there some name for this topological property?
- Regarding the second question, I believe it to be also positive.  One can iteratively cut away all intervals $I_{i,k}$ like above from $A$ when $A\cap I_{i,k}$ is a null set, then the resulting set $A'$ has the same measure as $A$ and $A'\subseteq D(A')$.  I could imagine that $A'$ is just $A\cap D(A)$ and $D(A)=D(A')$ the topological closure of $A'$.

Comment: See [MSE question #1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2993136/13130) and [MSE question # 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4103422/13130) (also my comments in #2). Also, Chapter I of Herbert Charles Parrish's 1955 Ph.D. dissertation [**On the Symmetric Structure of Unconditioned Point Sets and Real Functions**](https://etd.ohiolink.edu/apexprod/rws_olink/r/1501/10?) and [*New topologies from old via ideals*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2324512) (later part about generalization of C-B theorem) by Jankovic/Hamlet (1990).

Comment: FYI, sets $D$ with the property that the intersection of every nonempty open set with $D$ has positive outer measure ("outer" can be omitted if we assume $D$ is measurable) are called [measure dense sets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22measure+dense%22+%22set%22&filter=0) or [metrically dense sets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22metrically+dense%22+%22set%22&filter=0) (the latter term more often used in older literature).